# mlflow: problems with pip installation

Tags: pip, python-import, python-3.7, importerror, mlflow

I read through many threads regarding installation issues using pip. However, I could find a solution to help me fix my problem.
I installed mlflow with :

```
    pip3 install mlflow
```

so mlflow is installed in /usr/local/bin/mlflow

Since it is not in /Users/xxxx/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages, I get "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mlflow' error when I try to run code that imports mlflow module. How should I fix this?

Comment: Try both pip install and pip3 install.
It helped me. Sometimes our local mapping of pip and pip3 could be complicated in terms of dependencies

Answer (score 5):

Python modules are not global. Every module is installed and can be used with one Python.

You seems to have at least two Pythons — the system Python and anaconda. The command

```
pip3 install mlflow
```

seems to install the module to the system Python. Check it with `pip3 --version`.

To install the module to anaconda you need to use anaconda's `pip`. Something like

```
/Users/xxxx/opt/anaconda3/bin/python -m pip install mlflow
```

Comment: Thank you!  I tried        `python -m pip install mlflow`    and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Quite late, but rather than modifying path I'm doing `python -m mlflow ui`, where `python` points to whatever venv I'm using.